# How to get visible row of table in Angular JS after doing filtration

Tags: angularjs

I am showing list on table using html (table, tr, td) and angularJS. Table also contains filters on columns. Table is populating data properly and filters are working properly using AngularJS.

After doing some filtration, I want to get only visible rows in one of my  angularJS's function.

How can I get only the Visible Rows of a Table in angularJS after Few Filters?

Please note that I am not using any checkboxes or radio buttons with data list.

Please see my code below:

```
var myapp=angular.module("myapp",[]);

myapp.controller('ctrcommodity',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.commodity={
     allPreferredCommodity: [
        {
          "commodityId": "2016070011220000141",
          "commodityName": "Computer (PC)"
        },
        {
          "commodityId": "2016080011220000004",
          "commodityName": "Laptop"

        },
        {
          "commodityId": "2016070011220000032",
          "commodityName": "Keyboard"
        },
        {
          "commodityId": "2016080011220000054",
          "commodityName": "Mouser"
        }
      ]
    };

    $scope.getVisibleRows=function()
    {
        //want to get details of visible rows after filtration
    }

}]);                  

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Commodity Id</th>
        <th>Commodity Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtcid" id="txtcid" ng-model="s.commodityId"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtcname" id="txtcname" ng-model="s.commodityName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="commoditylist in commodity.allPreferredCommodity | filter:s">
        <td>{{commoditylist.commodityId}}</td>
        <td>{{commoditylist.commodityName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="6" height="50">
            <input type="button" value="Show Visible Rows" ng-click="getVisibleRows()">
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like the follwing . I am changing your function as

```
$scope.getVisibleRows=function(arrayData,s)
    {
        console.log(s);

        $scope.filerList=$filter('filter')(arrayData,s);
        alert(      $scope.filerList);
        //want to get details of visible rows after filtration
    }
```

and similarly change it is html also like ng-`click="getVisibleRows(commodity.allPreferredCommodity,s)"`

dont forget to inject filter to controller like myapp.controller('ctrcommodity',`['$scope','$filter',function($scope,$filter)`

Comment: thanks for your reply!! but it is not working on alert it is showing all commodity list in object.

Comment: just use  for(var i=0;i<$scope.filerList.length;i++){
   alert($scope.filerList[i].commodityName);
  }      to see the out put as alert

Comment: this loop is showing all value i.e. computer (PC), laptop, keyboard, mouse. Suppose I type Lap in s.commodityName textbox and click on "Show Visible Rows" button then it should show Laptop only. please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: it will. search type some thing and click on the button.it will show only items after filtering